Cut a number from row and insert into new column
I have a table where one column contains a long description with a street number and I want to pick that value , like we have three rows below:
Streetnum_12345678 /*+ INDEX(@"SEL$EECA6CD9" "wlf_assignment_records_f"@"SEL$214" "WLF_ASSIGNMENT_REC_F_N26") */
Streetnum12345678 /*+ MATERIALIZE(@"SEL$10") LEADING(@"SEL$5977F6F8" "DHA"@"SEL$11" "DFLA"@"SEL$12" "IO"@"SEL$14" "B"@"SEL$14" "T"@"SEL$14" "DOO_PROJECTS"@"SEL$13" "WDD"@"SEL$17") */
12345678_bsfg3y5fhya9d_4275961544 13112260617370893476 17045227932719343467
So from above three rows of a column I only need to pick value 12345678 from each row and insert as a new column like Streetnum , can some body help me how can i achieve it

About what tool/programming language are you talking? And please format your question in a more readable format so that readers can see exactly see what you mean.

Thanks jhole I am talking about pl sql here and so here we have a table with column streetname and streetdescription I need to create a third row cutting the value from streetdescription and by just picking the first occurrence of number and until the special character starts so my bascially I want to pick the value 12345678 from each row  . I tried to use substring with Select query but it does not help me much
